# Applescript clicking nested menu items

Tags: menu, applescript

very simple question but I am trying to click a menu item that is in a list in a menu - i.e. clicking "Text Encoding" in the menu brings up a list of different kinds of encoding. I want to choose a certain kind of encoding using applescript. Here's my attempt:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iChm"
    click menu item "Text Encoding" of menu "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
    click menu item 2 of last menu item
end tell
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: sorry i know its probably a stupid question - I couldn't find the answer anywhere though!

Comment: Did you check to ensure that UI elements are enabled? I don't recall what process "iChm" is, so this is as much as I can question right now.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. iChm is just a chm file reader. I want to click one of the items in the toolbar that is two levels in - if that makes sense? Also I tried the script for an item on level in (e.g. Edit menu "Select All") and noticed it is only implemented once I click on "Edit" in the toolbar. Thanks

Comment: *one level in. Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iChm"
    tell menu item "Text Encoding" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
        click menu item 3 of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

For some menu items you need to click the menu bar item first:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where it is frontmost)
    tell menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
        click
        click menu item "Open Recent" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be nice to know what you're trying to click exactly. If it is the "Unicode  (UTF-8)" item, notice that there are (probably a type-o by the developer) TWO spaces after Unicode:

```
"Unicode  (UTF-8)"
        ^^
```

So if you do:

```
tell application "System Events"
    click menu item "Unicode  (UTF-8)" of menu "Text Encoding" of menu item "Text Encoding" of menu "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1 of application process "iChm"
end tell
```

... it will work.